# What is the difference between (@StateObject & @StateObject) and (@StateObject & @ObservedObject) in Parent and Child Views

Tags: ios, swiftui, property-wrapper

## @StateObject & @StateObject in Both Parent and ChildView

```
import SwiftUI


class Counter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count: Int = 0
    
    func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var counter : Counter = Counter()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent Counter: \(counter.count)")
            Button("Increment Child Counter") {
                counter.increment()
            }
            ChildView(counter: counter)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @StateObject var counter: Counter
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child Counter: \(counter.count)")
            Button("Increment Child Counter") {
                counter.increment()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RandomNumberView: View {
    @State var randomNumber = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Random number is: \(randomNumber)")
            Button("Randomize number") {
                randomNumber = (0..<1000).randomElement()!
            }
        }.padding(.bottom)
        
        ContentView()
    }
}


#Preview {
    RandomNumberView()
}
```

## @StateObject & @ObservedObject in Parent and ChildView

```
import SwiftUI


class Counter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count: Int = 0
    
    func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var counter : Counter = Counter()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent Counter: \(counter.count)")
            Button("Increment Child Counter") {
                counter.increment()
            }
            ChildView(counter: counter)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var counter: Counter
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child Counter: \(counter.count)")
            Button("Increment Child Counter") {
                counter.increment()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RandomNumberView: View {
    @State var randomNumber = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Random number is: \(randomNumber)")
            Button("Randomize number") {
                randomNumber = (0..<1000).randomElement()!
            }
        }.padding(.bottom)
        
        ContentView()
    }
}


#Preview {
    RandomNumberView()
}
```

**Both Having the same Output View.**

I have checked many of the articles and my own cases in @StateObject vs @ObservedObject in childView But I don't find anything useful. So what's the difference in **this case**. I want the explanation for this to code how it works when @StateObject & @ObservedObject used in childView.

Comment: StateObject has storage and lifecycle management that is managed by SwiftUI ObservedObject does not. StateObject should always be private so option 1 is fundamentally wrong and you are allocating storage twice. State should also always be private because it is also a source of truth with storage. So that is wrong with both.

Comment: If you elaborate on the behavior you are seeing we could help more specifically.

Comment: You should avoid unnecessary `@StateObject` when don't need a reference type, i.e. not using delegates or Combine. Counter should be done with `@State` and for child View use `let` for read only or `@Binding var` for read/write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SwiftUI updates a `View` that has already been seen before, it restores the values of that view's `@State` and `@StateObject` properties to the values they had on the prior rendering.

So, the first time SwiftUI asks `ContentView` for its `body`, `ContentView` creates a `ChildView` and passes its (`ContentView`'s) `counter` to initialize `ChildView`'s `counter`.

When `counter`'s `@Published` `count` property changes, SwiftUI asks `ContentView` for its `body` again. `ContentView.body` creates another `ChildView` and again passes its `counter` down to initialize `ChildView`'s `counter`.

**However**, SwiftUI recognizes that this `ChildView` represents an update to the prior `ChildView`. So it throws away whatever was stored in this new `ChildView`'s `counter` and sets it to the `Counter` that was used the first time it saw this `ChildView`.

This doesn't make a difference in your example, because you only ever create one `Counter`.

Let's write a example where it does matter.

First, here's a simple `Button` that displays a count and increments the count when tapped, just using a `Binding`:

```
struct CountButton: View {
    @Binding var count: Int
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            count += 1
        } label: {
            Text("\(count)")
                .frame(width: 60)
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's a view that uses a `StateObject` to hold a `Counter` and pass its `count` to a `CountButton`:

```
struct ViewWithStateObject: View {
    @StateObject var counter: Counter

    var body: some View {
        GroupBox("View with StateObject") {
            CountButton(count: $counter.count)
                .frame(width: 300)
                .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

And here's a similar view that uses an `ObservedObject` instead:

```
struct ViewWithObservedObject: View {
    @ObservedObject var counter: Counter

    var body: some View {
        GroupBox("View with ObservedObject") {
            CountButton(count: $counter.count)
                .frame(width: 300)
                .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

And finally, here's a view that holds **two** `Counter` instances, each in a `StateObject`. It embeds both of the above views, and lets you choose which of its `Counter` instances to pass to both children:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var counter0: Counter = Counter()
    @StateObject private var counter1: Counter = Counter()
    @State var useCounter1 = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GroupBox("ContentView") {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        CountButton(count: $counter0.count)
                        CountButton(count: $counter1.count)
                    }
                    Toggle("Pass counter1 to children", isOn: $useCounter1)
                }
                .frame(width: 300)
                .padding()
            }

            ViewWithStateObject(counter: useCounter1 ? counter1 : counter0)
            ViewWithObservedObject(counter: useCounter1 ? counter1 : counter0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

If you tap the top left `CountButton` in this example, you'll find that both children are updated as the count increases. And the buttons in the children also increment the same count. They are all using `counter0`.

If you tap the top right `CountButton`, only it updates. The other buttons are not affected, because only that top right button uses `counter1`.

Next, tap the toggle. This makes `ContentView` pass `counter1` to the children.

Now, when you tap the top left button, both the top left button and the “View with StateObject” show the increment, but the “View with ObservedObject” button doesn't change. And if you tap the top right button, both it and the “View with ObservedObject” button show the increment, but the “View with StateObject” button doesn't change.

When you turn on the toggle, `ContentView` passes `counter1` to the children, instead of passing `counter0`. But, before SwiftUI asks `ViewWithStateObject` for its `body`, SwiftUI discards the contents of `ViewWithStateObject`'s `counter` property and replaces it with the prior contents. So it discards the new reference to `counter1` and restores the old reference to `counter0`. `ViewWithStateObject` will never switch to `counter1`.

Comment: Hopefully one day they make `@StateObject var` with missing object init a compilation error

Comment: They will not, because that would be source-breaking. Furthermore, [the `StateObject` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject#Initialize-state-objects-using-external-data) specifically discusses how to initialize an `StateObject` in your `init`.

Comment: It's crazy to me they added that example to the docs. It would make more sense to use the property wrapper as designed; make the `name` param optional and set it at the top of `body` (and have the object only do something if it has changed).

Answer (score 0):

You're right about both wrappers working exactly the same. They present the single source of truth. However, there are essential distinctions that you might need to know.

1. **@StateObject vs @StateObject**:

SwiftUI has a concept: Single Source of Truth (SSOT). This means it must be created in one place and pass the state through view hierarchy via [`ObservedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject) or [`EnviromentObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/environmentobject(_:)).

So this usage is totally wrong, even though it gets the same result.

---

2. **@StateObject vs @ObservedObject**

If you declare `@ObservedObject` in a View rather than passing it from elsewhere, it may get reset accidentally. `@StateObject` will not get this behavior. The right way to use it is like you did above, on the second example.

```swift
@ObservedObject var counter = Counter()
```

Comment: `@StateObject` is only for when you need a reference type in a `@State`, this isn't the case for the OP's counter

Answer (score -1):

`@StateObject` is only for when you need a reference type in a `@State`, i.e. when using a delegate or Combine pipeline. In your case of a counter you don't need that so should be using `@State var` in the parent `View` and either `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for read/write in any child Views (in both cases body will be called when the value changes), e.g.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Counter {
    var count: Int = 0 // any change to a struct's var is considered a change to the whole state struct thus body will be called.
    
    mutating func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter : Counter = Counter()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent Counter: \(counter.count)")
            Button("Increment Child Counter") {
                counter.increment()
            }
            ReadWriteChildView(counter: $counter)
            ReadChildView(counter: counter)
        }
    }
}

struct ReadWriteChildView: View {
    @Binding var counter: Counter
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child Counter: \(counter.count)")
            Button("Increment Child Counter") {
                counter.increment()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ReadChildView: View {
    let counter: Counter
    ...
```